# Intended use of ctrl+T in bash?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, history

I noticed bash has a short cut for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> which swaps the last two characters before the cursor.

I'm wondering why the engineers decided to include this.

- Was it inherited from a previous convention?
- Or is there a practical purpose that this is commonly used for?

Comment: Not an answer, but this isn't `bash`, as such, but `readline` (which bash uses for input at the prompt). Your bash is using `emacs` key-bindings; you can change to vi key-bindings if your an Editor Wars partisan ;) https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/vi-mode-in-bash/ There's a couple of "cheat-sheets" for `readline` here: http://readline.kablamo.org/emacs.html and http://readline.kablamo.org/vi.html.

Comment: Historically, the Emacs-style command-line editing features were initially developed in Bash, and then turned into a separate library — but that happened before the first release in 1989. The very first entry in [the `readline` `ChangeLog`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/ChangeLog#n402) hints at this. So originally the shortcut was handled in Bash itself, albeit briefly, before being pulled out into `readline` — but the shortcut came to Bash from Emacs (I don't know if it was invented in Emacs or came from elsewhere).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is inherited (by readline) from GNU Emacs, which uses <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> for transposing characters:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Transpose.html

Note that bash's line editor defaults to Emacs mode, but you can also switch it to vi mode, if you prefer.

Answer (score 69):

It's very useful to quickly fix typos:

```
sl
```

becomes

```
ls
```

with a single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to swap words too (*e.g.* when switching between `service` and `systemctl`...).

Historically speaking, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> feature came to Bash from Emacs in all likelihood. It probably was copied to Emacs from some other editor; it was present in Stanford's E editor (see [*Essential E*](http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/80/796/CS-TR-80-796.pdf) page 13) by 1980, and E had a strong impact on Richard Stallman (as described in [*Free as in Freedom*](https://sagitter.fedorapeople.org/faif-2.0.pdf)). It was implemented in very early versions of Bash, before its first release in 1989, when it was pulled out into the `readline` library where it lives today (the very first entry in the [`readline` `ChangeLog`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/ChangeLog#n402) hints at this).

Comment: Swapping words was something new & very helpful

Comment: Providing a numeric argument to Alt+T transposes the word at (or before) the cursor with the _n_-th word before that word. eg: Alt+2 Alt+T will modify `word1 word2 word3` to `word3 word2 word1` if performed at `word3`.

Comment: @crw that would be nice but alt+T doesn't swap words on my terminal. I just opens the menu item 'set title'.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride that's a shame, your terminal emulator is depriving you of a very useful shortcut...

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride there should be an option of the terminal emulator to disable menu access keys

Comment: Note that [ksh85](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V8/usr/man/man1/ksh.1) already had *`^T` Transpose current character with next character in emacs mode.  Transpose two previous characters in gmacs mode.* Likely already in the original implementation (ksh in 1983 included vi/emacs line editors that had been written for the Bourne shell earlier).

Answer (score 21):

This key combination, a binding inherited from the `emacs` text editor, causes the last 2 characters typed to be swapped at the end of the line, used in the middle of a line, it swaps the character at the left of the cursor and the one under the cursor.

It may seem vain to have a binding for such a seldom used feature that is easily achieved with a few more key strokes. Old timers such as I use it quite often and it used to save some transmission time back in the days of 300 baud modems, in the late '70s, especially in the middle of long lines.

A similar and more useful command, bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, transposes the words at the left and at the right of the cursor.

<kbd>T</kbd> was chosen because it is the initial letter of *transpose*. Other bindings with similar origin include:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, for *backward*, moves the cursor left one position,

  - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> moves the cursor left one word,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, for *forward*, moves the cursor right one position,

  - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> moves the cursor right one word,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, for *Anfang* or *ante*, moves the cursor to the beginning of the line,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, for *end*, moves the cursor to the end of the line,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, for *next*, retrieves the next line,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, for *previous*, retrieves the next line,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, for *delete*, deletes the character under the cursor,

  - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> deletes the word under the cursor,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, for *kill*, cuts the end of the line,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, for *yank*, pastes the contents of the clipboard,

These bindings, implemented in the GNU `readline` package, are therefore available in all programs that use it for user input, such as *bash*, but also *gdb*, *bc*, ...

Some of the are also available in other environments: The Firefox URL input line, text input fields in the OS/X graphical interface, and many X-based window managers.

*vim* users can select the corresponding bindings via an environment variable.

Comment: Yes, it's great for those like us who sometimes forget we're typing into a terminal rather than an Emacs; I still get caught out when using Firefox's textarea widgets (like this one now), which are missing these important bindings.  :-(

Comment: Is there a way you could pair up the character and word versions of related commands in your description?  It really helps the memory when you recognise that the `Alt` and `Ctrl` versions of those keystrokes are related in a consistent way.

Comment: @TobySpeight GTK+ supports an alternative Emacs-style keybinding theme so you can use some of these keybindings in Firefox.  `C-t` however seems to not do anything.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK%2B#Emacs_keybindings

Comment: @TobySpeight have you ever tried [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/)? It allows you to edit the contents of textareas in the editor of your choice.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen - I've heard of it, but not tried it (yet).  I'll follow that up...

Comment: I'm finding the back and forward commands you shared extremely useful.

Comment: `vi` users just use `x` followed by `p`.

Answer (score 11):

It is vrey useufl for corretcing smiple tpyos wehre yuo haev accidnetally trasnposed piars of lettres.

(Having severe RSI in both wrists, I end up using this a lot, personally...)

Comment: My eyes are bleeding

Answer (score 5):

A very quickly fix typos. effects the immediate 2 corrector block before the courser.

If you typed `ls-` and you want a space between `ls` & hyphen then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

This works if you have a space after hyphen & then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>